# asp.net mvc url routing (disable access to /index and query string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Suppose we have the following controller code and default to Home/Index and i have a domain www.abc.com.

How to i configure to make www.abc.com/home and www.abc.com/home/index as 404 page

```
 public HomeController : Controller {
        public ActionResult Index() {
        }
    }
```

Also suppose I have controller like this, I assume that user can access it following way. www.abc.com/home/index/1 or using query string www.abc.com/home/index/?id = 1. I would like to display 404 page for this url: www.abc.com/home/index/?id = 1. How can this be done?

```
public HomeController : Controller {
        public ActionResult Index(string id) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes method, this will make `/home` and `/home/index` show a 404:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Home",
    url: "",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

and this route will allow `/home/index/1` but will 404 for `/home/index/?id=1`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Home",
    url: "home/index/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

This is pretty basic routing in ASP.NET MVC. I recommend reading some of documentation that's out there for more information.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx